# hibernate table with 3 foreign keys

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm trying to map the following table to an entity.

[image: Involved Tables]
The mapping for the event table looks like this:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer _id;
@Column(name = "title")
private String _title;
@Column(name = "description")
private String _description;
@Column(name = "location")
private String _place;
@Column(name = "start")
private Date _start;
@Column(name = "end")
private Date _stop;
@Column(name = "points")
private int _points;
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "type")
private EventType _eventtype;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "event2work2instrumentation", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "event")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "work")})
private Set<WorkMapper> _works = new HashSet<>(0);

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "event2work2instrumentation", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "event")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "instrumentation")})
private Set<InstrumentationMapper> _instrumentations = new HashSet<>(0);
```

It works fine and i get all the data from the database, but when I try to store a new event which has a work and instrumentation assigned to it I get errors.

When the fields in the event2work2instrumentation table are configured to not be null, i get: field does not have a default value.

If I give the field default values I get:

```
SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row:
    a foreign key constraint fails (`schema`.`event2work2instrumentation`, CONSTRAINT `e2w2i_instrumentation_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`instrumentation`) REFERENCES `instrumentation` (`id`))
```

You have any ideas? May it depend on the Mappings of instrumentation and/or Work? These classes do not have a reference to event2work2instrumentation in their mapping.

Comment: I am not an expert but you may need to add `cascade = CascadeType.INSERT` or `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` to both `@ManyToMany()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use a map and the MapKeyJoinColumn annotation:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "event2work2instrumentation", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "event")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "instrumentation")})
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "work")
private Map<WorkMapper, InstrumentationMapper> _eventToWorkAndInstrumentationMappers = new HashMap<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try truncating both tables and then store the new FK. It happened to me when I had a object_related_id which wasn't in object table as an id